# Como creó una función para cambiar el estado de un registro cada vez que añada uno nuevo

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola estoy creando un sistema de reservaciones en PHP.

Lo que intento hacer es actualizar el campo de una tabla cada vez que se añade un nuevo registro.

Tengo una tabla llamada actividades la cuál tiene un campo llamado cupo.
Quiero que este se actulice (osea que decremente) cada vez que alguien hace una reservacion a esa actividad.

Comment: Podrías compartir las Tablas y Diagrama Entidad relación para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta ahí esta el E-R

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas cómo elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Agrega el código con el que has intentado y el detalle de el error que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

una vez que insertas la reservación, pode ejectuar este query

```
UPDATE actividades SET cupo = cupo - 1 WHERE id = "AQUI EL ID DE LA ACTIVIDAD";
```

El nada mas colocas el id de la actividad que ya tenias previamente cuando la creaste.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí esta el ejemplo completo con algo muy pero muy parecido a lo que quieres implementar (disculpa pero por tiempo lo hice resumido). En tu ER tienes el cupo como un Varchar creo que será mas complicado hacerlo así, por eso en el ejemplo lo  hice como int.

```
CREATE TABLE actividades (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 nombreActividad VARCHAR(255),
 cupo INT
);

CREATE TABLE reservaciones (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 reservacion VARCHAR(255),
 email VARCHAR(255),
 actividad_id INT,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_act_reserv` FOREIGN KEY (actividad_id) REFERENCES actividades (id)
);

INSERT INTO actividades (nombreActividad, cupo) VALUE ('Natación', 25);
INSERT INTO actividades (nombreActividad, cupo) VALUE ('Atletismo', 30);

-- Creamos el Trigger

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER update_cupo_actividad
  AFTER INSERT ON reservaciones FOR EACH ROW 
   UPDATE actividades SET cupo = cupo - 1 WHERE id = NEW.actividad_id;


INSERT INTO reservaciones (reservacion, email, actividad_id) VALUES ('X1', 'd@d.com',1);
INSERT INTO reservaciones (reservacion, email, actividad_id) VALUES ('X2', 'd@d1.com',1);

INSERT INTO reservaciones (reservacion, email, actividad_id) VALUES ('X3', 'd@d3.com',2);
INSERT INTO reservaciones (reservacion, email, actividad_id) VALUES ('X4', 'd@d4.com',2);
```

Saludos!